# ActionMailer link_to show action fails with "missing required keys: [:id]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm trying to put a link to show action into view rendered by rails action mailer.

**mailer.rb**

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "foo@bar.com"

  def catalog_download_request(email, catalog)
    @catalog = catalog

    mail({
         to: email
    })
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)" do
    resources :catalogs, :path => I18n.t("routes.catalogs"), only: [:index, :show]
  end

end
```

**development.rb:**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "http://localhost:3000" }
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "localhost",
  port: 1025
}

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

**My model where I'm calling mailer:**

```
class CatalogDownloadRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :catalog

  after_create :send_mail

  private

  def send_mail
    Mailer.catalog_download_request(email, catalog).deliver
  end

end
```

**That's what I tried in my view:**

```
<%= link_to @catalog %>
```

**error:**

> ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"catalogs", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :locale=>#} missing required keys: [:id]

**Another try:**

```
<%= link_to catalog_url(@catalog) %>
```

**error:**

> ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"index"}

I'm suspecting this is happening because my locale scope on routes.

If I use `<%= link_to catalog_url(@catalog) %>` in another view, it works.

**Solved with:**

```
<%= link_to catalog_url(:id => @catalog.id), catalog_url(:id => @catalog.id) %>
```

Comment: Same error for me.
Even when trying most simple example `<%= recording_url(@recording) %>` or `<%= recording_path(@recording) %>`
It is pretty basic rails app without anything special.

Comment: I think you need to do the same that worked for me: `recording_url(:id => @recording.id)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for `ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"index"}` is:

`link_to` requires two parameters (text and url) ([api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)). You only passed one. After you pass the text as the first argument, it will work correctly.

If you really want, according to the document, you pass nil as the first argument and then url as the second one.

Comment: link_to works well with just one parameter, it render the link with url as the text.

Comment: I'm sorry about the problem with my answer, but your answer is not clear enough for me since in other views that code works and at e-mail view don't. So, link_to works with single parameter, just not in that specific case. I appreciate that you tried to help me and although your answer in my point of view is not 100% correct, I'm setting it as solved.

Comment: The real trick to make it work was at this part of code: `catalog_url(:id => @catalog.id)`

Comment: Thanks (happy now :D). But I have to point out that link_to is never designed to accept single parameter. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to If you want url to be used as name, you pass nil as the first argument.

Comment: This answer is unrelated to the actual error and, from the comments above, appears to be unrelated to the actual fix.

Comment: @DavidMoles The question essentially contains two questions. The first question (which is in the title) is what I encountered, and solved by correcting my `link_to` call. Did you mean that I didn't try to answer the second question?

Comment: @lulalala You may be correct about the requirement for the first parameter as text, however the documentation DOES show a list of signatures, the last of which has url as the first and only required parameter.

Comment: @ChadM The last one requires you passing a block, which evaluates to text.